# PopOS LAN not working but WiFi works

Tags: internet, pop-os, lan

**LAN not working on my Pop OS.** The wifi still works though, it's been a day since this happened. I changed ports and all of the cable and the cable works for others as well but not on my laptop l.

Comment: Are you sure it's only your laptop? I have a hunch...

Comment: Yes, one of my friends laptop does work and gets connected to the ethernet, but mine doesn't

Comment: And if you reconnect your laptop back the way it was before you switched ports, does your laptop connect again?

Comment: No, it doesn't connect...nothing worked, tried all physically possible changes

Comment: What's the IP Address of your Ethernet Adapter?  Try `ifconfig` or `ip -a` and post it in your question